# How to create array of files to FormData from FileList?

Tags: javascript, node.js, form-data, filelist

My goal is to create field in `formData` which contains array of `File` objects

My code (with example of output in console):

```
const onChange = (e) => {
        const files = e.target.files // contains FileList itself
        console.log(files) // FileList {0: File, 1: File, length: 2}
        .....
        var _formData = new FormData();
        var filesArr = Array.from(files) // try to cast FileList to Array type
        console.log(filesArr) // (2) [File, File]
        formData.append("files", filesArr) 
        for (var value of _formData.entries()) {
                console.log(value[0], ',', value[1], ',', typeof (value[1]));
                // files , [object File],[object File] , string

                                }
```

The problem is that I receive `object File` with type `string` instead of needed array of files (objects). Are there any ways how can it be casted?

Comment: You should loop over your `files` array, and then call `formData.append` for each of the entries individually.

Comment: @CBroe do you mean that?

If so, I've tried this, it doesn't work:(

`files.ForEach(element => {
   formData.append("files", element)
  })`

Comment: Where is the part where you actually _send_ this to the server?

Comment: `BACKEND.get('/count_word_in_documents_total', _formData)
                                        .then(response => { console.log(response) })`

BACKEND is:

`export const BACKEND = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_BASE_URL,
})`

Comment: You're expecting to do file uploads with a _GET_ request ...? (Assuming the method nomen est omen here.)

Comment: do you mean part where I get files or where I actually send FormData?

Comment: I am talking about `BACKEND.get(...)`, which I would assume makes a GET request ...?

Comment: I'm expecting to send FomData and receive Json

Comment: File uploads only make sense using POST, not GET.

Comment: Anyway, it is not related to actual problem. The guy below answered that there is no way to pass array of files. So, there is no solution in such implementation:(

Comment: Of course you can add multiple files. You can add multiple _anything_, using the `append` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MDN, If the field value is different than String or Blob it will be automatically converted to String. because this type of field is always a string.

Comment: If I clearly understood, there is no way to do this?

Comment: yes sir. may I know why you need to check the type of form field?

Comment: if you talk about checking in console output this is just for debugging. So sad, that there is no solution, but thank you anyway:(

Comment: if you liked my answer please upvote :).

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to vote, but I press this button :)